# how to distribute celery periodic task which runs every 5min?

Tags: cron, celery

I have several tasks with `'schedule': crontab(minute='*/5'),`

They run every 5min that's divisible by 5.

Tasks scheduled with the `minute='*/5'` will be run at the same time.

Can you somehow distribute them? like `minute='*/5' + 1` ( remainder is 1 after dividing by 5)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation of `celery` you can't use format like `minute='*/5' + 1`. What you can do is to use explicit definition of minutes to run the task like:

```
minute='1,6,11,16,21,26,31,36,41,46,51,56'
```

P.S. Records like this are usual practice in UNIX/Linux world